# Is it legal to install Google apps unofficially?

Tags: terms-of-service, google

May Google sue me if I install Google apps unofficially on my device (from [The Open GApps Project](https://opengapps.org/) for example) and sign in with my account? or will Google delete my account instead?

The need for this is because Windows Subsystem for Android doesn't come with Google apps pre-installed.

What if the apps are not opened directly by the user, but only for compatibility with unquestionably-legally-downloaded apps that require them?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a novel problem that you're solving for. you might have better luck on with a question on stackoverflow asking how to test for what you need to test for.